# How do I pass a request parameter from a URL to a function that returns an object of the same name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to pass a request parameter from an express router request to a function that will return an object of the same name, however the function returns the parameter name.

I've looked at the typeof the function parameter and it's type 'object' however req.params returns type string. How do i circumvent this?

```
router.get('/about/:place', (req, res) => {

// the object
  Mombasa = {
    "Destination": "Mombasa",
    "Price": 12000,
    "Likes": 0,
    "Gallery": [{
        "image": "https://traveldiscoverkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Mombasa-2-768x499.jpg"
    }, {
        "image": "https://i2.wp.com/buildesign.co.ke/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/ez.jpg"
    }]
};

// function that returns the object
  getPlace = (placeName) => {
    return placeName;
}

  // trying to send reaponse of whole object
  res.json(getPlace(req.params.place));
});
```

expected result:

{"Destination":"Mombasa","Price":12000,"Likes":0,"Gallery":[{"image":"https://traveldiscoverkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Mombasa-2-768x499.jpg"},{"image":"https://i2.wp.com/buildesign.co.ke/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/ez.jpg"}]}

actual result:

"Mombasa"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to have a parent object for your `Mombasa` object so you can use property keys to get the desired object like this:

```
const myObjects = {
  Mombasa: {
    "Destination": "Mombasa",
    "Price": 12000,
    "Likes": 0,
    "Gallery": [{
        "image": "https://traveldiscoverkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Mombasa-2-768x499.jpg"
    }, {
        "image": "https://i2.wp.com/buildesign.co.ke/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/ez.jpg"
    }]
  }
};
```

Then you can get this object by using the key "Mombasa":

```
  getPlace = (placeName) => {
    return myObjects[placeName];
  }
```

Comment: You could also achieve this by using an array of objects. Like `const objects = [{ Destination: "Mombasa" }];` and then use `Array.prototype.find()` to find the desired object in your `getPlace` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your Object must be like following,

and also move the methods and object outside of router.

```
router.get('/about/:place', (req, res) => {
    // trying to send reaponse of whole object
    res.json(getPlace(req.params.place));
});

let obj = {
    Mombasa: {
        "Destination": "Mombasa",
        "Price": 12000,
        "Likes": 0,
        "Gallery": [{
            "image": "https://traveldiscoverkenya.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Mombasa-2-768x499.jpg"
        }, {
            "image": "https://i2.wp.com/buildesign.co.ke/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/ez.jpg"
        }]
    }
}

// function that returns the object
getPlace = (placeName) => {
    return obj[placeName];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Am actually requiring the function from another file that get's the objects from a DB. It's the object manipulation that was the problem